# Magento data migration tool - bin/magento migrate:data SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am migrating from magento 1 (1.7.0.2) to magento 2 (2.3.5) and during the data migration process I get into a constant error.

Using the migrate:data command I get the following error, I've tried to see if anyone else has had the same issue but can't find an exact replication of it.

Is anyone able to help or provide some guidance on next steps trying to solve this?

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
> 'table_name' for key
> 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_CODE'

Answer (score 0):

Deleting duplicated frows from `eav_attribute_group` fixed this issue.